# Unable to instantiate rootViewController from within AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

My onboarding process (login/signup) lives outside of the UINavigationController chain, but when the login is authenticated I call a method in the appdelegate thats supposed to instantiate the rootViewController and then push to it. I've tried two things:

The snippet above worked in appDelegate from a method that gets called when a local notification is responded to, but not in this case.

```
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
  self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

And heres another method I tried:

```
 let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let dashboard = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController

   rootViewController!.navigationController?.popToViewController(dashboard, animated: true)
```

Neither of these work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My login view controller also live outside of my tab bar controller so this is what I did:

[image]

In the appDelegate:

```
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    let storyboard  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LoginViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


    return true
}
```

then I have a method in my loginViewContoller.swift:

```
    @IBAction func loginPushed(sender: AnyObject) {


    //other stuff here 

    let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let first = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstNavController") as! UINavigationController
    let second = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondNavController") as! UINavigationController
    let third = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdNavController") as! UINavigationController

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let controllers = [first, second, third]

    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
    appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = tabBarController
    appDelegate.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't call the 'popToRootViewController', you can reassignment the window.rootViewController~